# Counting the number of one bits in a number using two's complement

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I have the following function for counting the number of one bits:

```
/** Count the number of 1 bits in num */
int bitcount(int num)
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(; num != 0; num = num >> 1)
    {
        if(num & 1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

It works fine, however the book I am reading (K&R) says that there is a faster version of bitcount that relies on the fact that in a two's complement number system, `x &= (x - 1)` deletes the rightmost bit in x. I need help leveraging this information to create a faster bitcount algorithm.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that unless you are doing some extremely performance-critical code, there's not much point in getting faster than what you currently have

Comment: `x &= (x - 1)` You can just do that in a loop until `x` is 0. The number of iterations for that will be the number of 1 bits whereas your solution will need to iterate until the highest 1 bit is found. Simple example: For `1000` in binary your solution will iterate 4 times whereas the other solution will need only 1 iteration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer

Comment: ""It works fine," --> No. Tests are inadequate.  Try `bitcount(-1)`.  Function fails for all negative values.  Why worry about speed when functionality is broken?  This is a good example of misplaced priorities.

Comment: If `x` is not negative, `x & (x - 1)` clears the lowest set bit, regardless of how negative numbers are stored. Two's complement is irrelevant; the only requirement is a binary encoding. Two's complement is only relevant if `x` is negative; as chux points out above, the function fails on negative íntegers.

Comment: @rici Thanks. I think I am starting to get it a little bit. Basically, rather than starting from left going to right cancelling out the ones, this time you start from right going to left. The & thing helps you jump straight to the next one. Interesting, it seems that this C thing has alot going on. I'll try out the advice.

Comment: @rici I figured it out. thx